# how to use else condition outside the For Loop in java

Tags: java

When the image name is found then the condition will be break and set the name in JLable. But when image name not found, the else condition, should be run.

Where to write else condition? i want to show the message when image name is not found.

```
for( k=0;k<imageList.length;k++) {
    if(imageList[k].equals(name)) { 
        lblShowName.setText("Image Code : "+imageList[k]);
        ImageIcon imgicon = new ImageIcon(file+"\\"+imageList[k]);
        lblImage.setIcon(imgicon);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a boolean variable,  if variable is false then show your error message

Your code can be modified this way

```
boolean isFound = false;
for( k=0;k<imageList.length;k++) {
 if(imageList[k].equals(name)) {
    isFound = true; 
    lblShowName.setText("Image Code : "+imageList[k]);
    ImageIcon imgicon = new ImageIcon(file+"\\"+imageList[k]);
    lblImage.setIcon(imgicon);
    break;
  }
}

if(!isFound){
  //your error message
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in the first answer by @Ezio if-else scope is limited to for loop it can't be outside the loop so the above implementation works

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an `else` statement without an `if` statement. The scope of the `if` statement is inside the loop so you wont be able to use `else` outside the for loop.

You can have some kind of a flag which will be set if the label is set.

```
boolean labelSet = false;
for( k=0;k<imageList.length;k++) {
    if(imageList[k].equals(name)) { 
        lblShowName.setText("Image Code : "+imageList[k]);
        ImageIcon imgicon = new ImageIcon(file+"\\"+imageList[k]);
        lblImage.setIcon(imgicon);
        labelSet = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(!labelSet) {
    //show the error message here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of for loop tou should check whether the image has been set or not:

```
for( k=0;k<imageList.length;k++) {
    if(imageList[k].equals(name)) { 
        lblShowName.setText("Image Code : "+imageList[k]);
        ImageIcon imgicon = new ImageIcon(file+"\\"+imageList[k]);
        lblImage.setIcon(imgicon);
        break;
    }
}

if (lblImage.getIcon() == null) {
// do some else actions
}
```